# Is it true Gilthunder statement about Meliodas and Ban being the strongest nanatsu no taizai members?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In OVA 2 of Nanatsu no Taizai, Gilthunder says about Meliodas and Ban, "They arent simple holy knights, it is said the 2 of them are the strongests of The Seven Deadly Sins"

Is this true? I thought Escanor was said to be the strongest. Moreover, the power levels figures which appears for Ban dont look any special (it's said that after the Hunter Festival he's stronger than that, probably higher than a weakened Galand, with this he still could be weaker than several members) , and also if I recall correctly in the first season it's mentioned Diane it's the physically strongest.

Is it true Gilthunder statement about Meliodas and Ban being the strongest nanatsu no taizai members?

Answer (score 1):

The tricky thing with calling someone the ***strongest*** in any show is that it is very quickly opinion based. One could say that Escanor is easily the strongest member of the group because he just obliterates everyone he sees. Meliodas has his full-counter move which is also a feature one could use to call him the ***strongest***. Ban is immortal. He litterally can't die. This feature of Ban could be used to argue that he is the strongest member (he also has the whole muscle buff mode thingie).

The point I am trying to make here is that (in the way i see it) Gilthunder ***believes*** Meliodas and Ban to be the strongest members based on things he knows/has seen. I don't believe that you should take his statement 100% at face value when it comes to actual power level scaling.